# C# How can I hide the cursor in a winforms app?

Tags: c#, winforms, mouse-cursor

Im developing a touchscreen app and I need to hide the cursor whenever it is within the main Form.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Simply put

```
Cursor.Hide();
```

is all I needed in the forms constructor.

Comment: are you sure about "this.Cursor" AFAIK you should use static Cursor class i.e. Cursor.Hide()

Comment: You are correct ... a typo on my part it should be 'Cursor.Hide();' without the this.

Comment: How do you toggle it?  Calling the methods outside of the form's constructor don't seem to have any effect. :-/

Comment: It should be noted that Cursor.Hide(); and Cursor.Show(); need to be __balanced__!!!